# issue while assigning values to variables in for loop |bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, for-loop

I am getting command not found error for code below:

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x
for i in `cat  output`;
do
eval "MASTER_$i = $(/usr/efm-2.0/bin/efm cluster-status $i 2>/dev/null |grep "Master"  |head -1 |awk -F " " {'print$2'})";
echo -e "$MASTER_$i";
done
```

Debug output is:

```
./test.sh
++ cat output
+for i in '`cat  output`'
++ /usr/efm-2.0/bin/efm cluster-status abc
++ grep Master
++ head -1
++ awk -F ' ' '{print$2}'
+eval 'MASTER_abc = 10.x.x.x'
++ MASTER_abc = 10.x.x.x
**./test.sh: line 5: MASTER_abc: command not found**
+echo -e abc
abc
```

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to use a `while` loop.

Comment: You aren't iterating over the lines of your file; you are iterating over the whitespace-separated words resulting from the contents of your file being subjected to pathname expansion. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces around the `=`...   If you try running `eval "i = 1"`, it will try running command `i`, with parameters `=` and `1` instead of setting `i` to be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Strongly recommend you use a bash associative array instead of dynamic variable names:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
declare -A master
while IFS= read -r line; do
    master["$line"]=$( /usr/efm-2.0/bin/efm cluster-status "$line" 2>/dev/null |awk '/Master/ {print $2; exit}' )
done < output.file

for line in "${!master[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$line" "${master[$line]}"
done
```